# Assigning data from a class list to another class list

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following class which is populated after de-serializing a JSON string:

```
public class Doors
{
    public List<Door> doors { get; set; }
}

public class Door
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool elevator { get; set; }
}
```

JSON string:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Doors>(response.Content);
// "{\"doors\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Main Door\",\"elevator\":false},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Back Door\",\"elevator\":false}]}"
```

The data maps to my class fine, I'm then trying to pass the class data to another class:

```
public class WS4APIResult
{   
    public List<Door> doors { get; set; } = new List<Door>();      
}

public class Door
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool elevator { get; set; }
}

return new WS4APIResult() {         
    doors = result.doors
}
```

With the following error: any ideas please?

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<WS4PortalApi.Models.Door>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<WS4PortalApi.Domain.Door>'`

Comment: You can't cast an object to another type just because they have the same property names. Write a "copy" method than copies ease property or use a 3rd party library like Automapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two c#-Files refer to different classes if you type `Door`. You need to implement a conversion between `WS4PortalApi.Models.Door` and `WS4PortalApi.Domain.Door`.

Like:

```cs
public static WS4PortalApi.Domain.Door DoorConvert(WS4PortalApi.Models.Door door)
```

then you can use linq to generate a new List

```cs
doors = result.doors
    .Select(d => DoorConvert(d))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to map the properties of your domain object to those of the model.
I normally create a method for this like:

```
var doors = new List<Model.Door>();
foreach(door in result.doors)
{
     var doorModel = new Model.Door
     {
         id = door.id,
         name = door.name,
         elevator = door.elevator
     };
     doors.Add(doorModel);
}
return doors;
```

Or you can use a library like automapper.